# How to check if the data already exists on the table?

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I have a table named `users` two of it's fields are `login` and `name`.
These fields `can not` be duplicate.
When the user are going to create a new registration, I already made a method to check if that `name/login` already exists or not.  
But the user can also edit his `login/name`.
When the user enters on the page to edit his registration data, it already fills the fields with the current data.  
I have 3 fields `[NAME] [EMAIL] [LOGIN]`. 
The user can edit only 1 of this or all of them at once ...  
How may I create a method to check if that `name/login`already exists or not when he try to edit it ?
 Maybe a Query ?
 A `select count` on the `login` then on the `name` field ?

--UPDATE--
here's my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14640696/2054434)

Answer (score 1):

You should leave this up to the database system you are using and handle any errors it may throw.  All database systems (Access, Oracle, MS SQL, etc) allow you to mark a table field as being Unique.  This means that the table can only hold one records with a field(s) with that value.  If you try to add more than one record with a same field, you will be thrown an error.  Your application should catch that error and alert the user.  If you post what kind of database system you are using I can show you how to do this.

Edit:

Heres is an example.  This uses the SqlClient.SqlException exception class.  I'm not sure what the error code is for unique constraints but I added a variable in the catch that you can place a break point on to get.  Just change the if statement to match that error code:

```
    Try
        'your database insert attempt here
    Catch ex As SqlClient.SqlException
        Dim sqlErrorNumber = ex.ErrorCode
        If (sqlErrorNumber = 1) Then
            Me.lblWarning.Text = "Please select a unique ID"
            Me.lblWarning.Visible = True
            Me.lblWarning.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            Me.lblWarning.Font.Bold = True
        End If

    End Try
```

In the aspx page:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblWarning" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Hi @jason ! I'm using `MySql`... So if I make something like: `try{} catch(Exception ex) { throw new Exception ("" + ex.Message);` ? What you think ? I didn't know about this `Unique` thing ;s

Comment: Yup, that's the way to go.  You can set the unique constraint like this, if you are writing the SQL DDL:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp or if you are using mySql workbench, I believe you can write click on the column and select "Unique"

Comment: And is there a different way to work with it ? Maybe make a custom warning when try to insert/edit a duplicate record...

Comment: That is ideal.  Have a label on your page that has visibility set to true. Catch any errors while trying to add to the db. If the error is due to a unique constraint problem, change the label's viability to true and add some custom text, like "Please Select A Unique Name".

Comment: Give a few minutes and I'll post an example

Comment: Hey man, I found a problem. With `Unique` field, even when i'm just `UPDATING´ it fires the excepetion, so it won't work for me ;s  
I guess I'll need a method to check it ;s

Comment: Just make sure you dont update to a value that already exists.  Otherwise it should not fire an exception.

Comment: As I said, when the users goes to the `edit` page, the fields are already filled according to it's login, so if he edit only the `login`, the `name` and `email` will stay the same... So I guess i need e method =\

Answer (score 0):

What is your primary key here?

I suggest, Adding new identity column to your table will solve the issue.

You can edit the row based on the identity column.

For Ex: Add [UserID] field and made it unique identity column.  then perform update operations based on userid in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a column ID or if username column is not set like UNIQUE you can use this function :

function user_exists($username){
      $username = sanitize($username); // [sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)
    return(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_name) FROM user_table WHERE username = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

For New Members / Or if current User wants to edit his username
this function return false if username is not registered and true if it is

Comment: Could you pass it to C#? I'm using `asp.net`... And i don't know php ;\

Comment: i post the function in C# code  into my demo site [Link to see](http://neuerra.com/demo/user_exist.txt)

Comment: Thanks man ! But why it sets the `_retValue = true` on the `catch exception`?

Comment: Its working, well, so-so, here's my query: `string sql = "SELECT COUNT(login) FROM usuarios WHERE login = @login";`. Even when there's no login = @login, it returns me the value of `1`. Wasn't suppose to return 0 ? If there's no login matching ?

Comment: on the catch exception,returns true because, if error if the error happens, so for prevention, not allows to make the change or the new registration

Comment: have you try thee debug?,   in query you don't need the count, SELECT * FROM usertable where login = @Login

Comment: Hi @Flavius69 I updated my question, can you check that query and tell it if it's ok using that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use unique fields in your database, try catch in php or asp and ajax technique to get sure that the fields are filled or not with the informations that are you typing now.